# Aggregating row values in MySQl or Snowflake

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to calculate the std dev. min and max of the mer_data array into 3 other fields called std_dev,min_mer and max_mer grouped by mac and timestamp.
This needs to be done without flattening the data as each mer_data row consists of 4000 float values and multiplying that with 700k rows gives a very high dimensional table.
The mer_data field is currently saved as varchar(30000) and maybe Json format might help, I'm not sure.
Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

This can be done in Snowflake or MySQL.
Also, the query needs to be optimized so that it does not take much computation time.

Comment: In MySQL - parse to separate values then aggregate and get needed values.

Comment: could you provide any documentation or query for it

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table will parse. The rest of the query is simple - grouping, aggregation, calculations...

Comment: I am fairly new to this, could you kindly query it down for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't want to split the data up, you will need to if you want to do it in pure SQL. Snowflake has no problems with such aggregations.

```
WITH fake_data(mac, mer_data) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('abc','43,44.25,44.5,42.75,44,44.25,42.75,43'),
        ('def','32.75,33.25,34.25,34.5,32.75,34,34.25,32.75,43')
)
SELECT f.mac,
    avg(d.value::float) as avg_dev,
    stddev(d.value::float) as std_dev,
    MIN(d.value::float) as MIN_MER,
    Max(d.value::float) as Max_MER
FROM fake_data f, table(split_to_table(f.mer_data,',')) d
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I would however discourage the use of strings in the grouping process, so would break it apart like so:

```
WITH fake_data(mac, mer_data, timestamp) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('abc','43,44.25,44.5,42.75,44,44.25,42.75,43', '01-01-22'),
        ('def','32.75,33.25,34.25,34.5,32.75,34,34.25,32.75,43', '02-01-22')
), boost_data AS (
    SELECT seq8() as seq, *
    FROM fake_data
), math_step AS (
  SELECT f.seq,
      avg(d.value::float) as avg_dev,
      stddev(d.value::float) as std_dev,
      MIN(d.value::float) as MIN_MER,
      Max(d.value::float) as Max_MER
  FROM boost_data f, table(split_to_table(f.mer_data,',')) d
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT b.mac,
    m.avg_dev,
    m.std_dev,
    m.MIN_MER,
    m.Max_MER, 
    b.timestamp
FROM boost_data b
JOIN math_step m
    ON b.seq = m.seq
ORDER BY 1;
```

| MAC | AVG_DEV | STD_DEV | MIN_MER | MAX_MER | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 43.5625 | 0.7529703087 | 42.75 | 44.5 | 01-01-22 |
| def | 34.611111111 | 3.226141056 | 32.75 | 43 | 02-01-22 |

### performance testing:

so using this SQL to make 70K rows of 4000 values each:

```
create table fake_data_tab AS
WITH cte_a AS (
   SELECT SEQ8() as s
   FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT =>70000))
), cte_b AS (
   SELECT a.s, uniform(20::float, 50::float, random()) as v
   FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT =>4000))
   CROSS JOIN cte_a a
)
SELECT s::text as mac
    ,LISTAGG(v,',') AS mer_data
    ,dateadd(day,s,'2020-01-01')::date as timestamp
FROM cte_b
GROUP BY 1,3;
```

takes 79 seconds on a XTRA_SMALL,

now with that we can test the two solutions:

The second set of code (group by numbers, with a join):

```
WITH boost_data AS (
    SELECT seq8() as seq, *
    FROM fake_data_tab
), math_step AS (
  SELECT f.seq,
      avg(d.value::float) as avg_dev,
      stddev(d.value::float) as std_dev,
      MIN(d.value::float) as MIN_MER,
      Max(d.value::float) as Max_MER
  FROM boost_data f, table(split_to_table(f.mer_data,',')) d
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT b.mac,
    m.avg_dev,
    m.std_dev,
    m.MIN_MER,
    m.Max_MER, 
    b.timestamp
FROM boost_data b
JOIN math_step m
    ON b.seq = m.seq
ORDER BY 1;
```

takes **1m47s**

the original group by strings/dates

```
SELECT f.mac,
    avg(d.value::float) as avg_dev,
    stddev(d.value::float) as std_dev,
    MIN(d.value::float) as MIN_MER,
    Max(d.value::float) as Max_MER,
    f.timestamp
FROM fake_data_tab f, table(split_to_table(f.mer_data,',')) d
GROUP BY 1,6
ORDER BY 1;
```

takes **1m46s**

Hmm, so leaving the "mac" as a number made the code very fast (~3s), and dealing with strings in ether way changed the data processed from 1.5GB for strings and 150MB for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers were in rows, not packed together like that, we can discuss how to do it in SQL.

In rows, `GROUP_CONCAT(...)` can construct a commalist like you show, and `MIN()`, `STDDEV()`, etc can do the other stuff.

If you continue to have the commalist, the do the rest of work in you app programming language.  (It is very ugly to have SQL pick apart an array.)